# SqlDependency caching in a wcf service not evicting

Tags: c#, wcf, caching, sqldependency

I have a wcf service which I make some database queries. And for not hammering the database I want to cache some of the queries. I searched and found that `SqlDependency` class and `System.Runtime.Caching`   could be used for this purpose. Then I've found these articles [link1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/167282/NET-MemoryCache-with-SqlChangeMonitor), [link2](http://serena-yeoh.blogspot.de/2014/02/runtime-caching-with-sqlchangemonitor.html). I figured that 2nd article takes it on step ahead and updates the cache too. But whatever I do, I could not manage to get it working. Below there is my service code.

```
public class LocalDatabase : ILocalDatabase
{
    public LocalDatabase ()
    {
        SqlDependency.Start(connectionString);
        _cache = MemoryCache.Default;
    }

    public List<string> GetData ( string value )
    {
        if ( MemoryCache.Default["exceptions"] == null )
        {
            // Create a policy.
            var policy = new CacheItemPolicy();

            // Load data into Cache Item.
            var exceptions = new List<string>();

            using ( var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString) )
            using ( var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Exception] FROM [myDb].[dbo].[ServiceException]", connection) )
            {
                var sqlDependency = new SqlDependency();
                sqlDependency.AddCommandDependency(command);
                connection.Open();

                using ( var result = command.ExecuteReader() )
                    while ( result.Read() )
                        exceptions.Add(result.GetString(0));

                var sqlMonitor = new SqlChangeMonitor(sqlDependency);

                policy.ChangeMonitors.Add(sqlMonitor);

                /// Events
                //sqlDependency.OnChange += sqlDep_OnChange;
                //policy.UpdateCallback = Exceptions_CacheUpdateCallback; 
            }

            // Set Cache Item into cache with the policy.
            MemoryCache.Default.Add("exceptions", exceptions, policy);
        }

        return MemoryCache.Default.Get("exceptions") as List<string>;
    }

    void sqlDep_OnChange ( object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e )
    {
        /// not firing this
    }

    void Exceptions_CacheUpdateCallback ( CacheEntryUpdateArguments args )
    {
        /// not firing this either
    }
}
```

In the first article, it doesn't even tied the events, but still claims it works, thus I removed the event handlers all together, but nothing changes. The problem is on first call to the service method it loads the cache from db, and the next calls gets their response from cache it is pretty good, but when a db change occurs either an insert or an update or a delete, it does not evict the cache, so it keeps giving the deprecated results. Then I have uncommented the event handlers, and those event got never fired either.

**Edit:** Btw, I have executed these two commands on sql server too.

```
ALTER DATABASE database_name SET TRUSTWORTHY ON WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
ALTER DATABASE database_name SET ENABLE_BROKER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
```

What I might be missin here?

**Edit2:** My other concern is as far as I know the default service behaviour of this is `InstanceContextMode.PerCall`. Will it affect this dependency concept? Or should I change the instance context mode too?

I can give more details if needed.

Comment: Where do you call [`SqlDependency.Start()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.start(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: It's in the constructor of my service class. Which I have some doubts about too that I forgot to include here.

Comment: So 'Start()' is called, once per service (stricly is per appdomain) lifetime, and you don't call 'Stop()' prematurely? (Stop should be called only once at shutdown)

Comment: Yes I call the `Start()` method but don't call `Stop()`. As you said I don't think it affects the behaviour. I've edited the question btw.

Comment: some reading: [The Mysterious Notification](http://rusanu.com/2006/06/17/the-mysterious-notification/) to understand how it works, [Troubleshooting Query Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177469.aspx) and [Troubleshooting Dialogs](http://rusanu.com/2005/12/20/troubleshooting-dialogs/) for investigating what goes on, and [Remove pooling for data changes from a WCF front end](http://rusanu.com/2007/11/01/remove-pooling-for-data-changes-from-a-wcf-front-end/) for a similar example to your case.

Comment: A shot in the dark: run `ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::database_name TO sa`

Comment: I have read the first article you've given before, and I will check all back again. Thanks for the effort. I will tell the outcomes.

Comment: I moved the article code to github https://github.com/rusanu/WCFQN, just tested it and works fine.

Comment: Sorry for bugging but I wanted to share that I have found out the problem, which is my sql query :/ I will reconstruct it according to the supported select query standards of sql notification concept.

Comment: Right, the table must contain only two part names: `[dbo].[ServiceException]`. I originally scrutinized the query for the usual problem (using only one part name) but I missed the issue of using a three part name. I must be getting old...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out I have constructed my sql query in a wrong format which violates the rules declared [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181122%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). Below is the sample of my mistake and the correction of it.

My wrong query:

```
SELECT p.Id, d.Id
FROM [MyDb].[dbo].[Personnel] p, [MyDb].[dbo].[Department] d
WHERE p.DepartmentId = d.Id
```

The corrected version:

```
SELECT [dbo].[Personnel].Id, [dbo].[Department].Id
FROM [dbo].[Personnel] INNER JOIN [dbo].[Department]
  ON [dbo].[Personnel].DepartmentId = [dbo].[Department].Id
```